# redirect to admin dashboard from my custom module controller

Tags: admin, dashboard

I have a requirement, where admin is performing certain action on a custom module, he should be redirected to admin-dashboard on error.
I tried redirection codes with different values but they lead to 404 page.
Moreover the admin url is customized not a customary one.
its like admin.thesitename.com/index.php/securecontrolpanel

i am still trying but decided to ask here :)  if i can get a quick help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is somehow unclear but I can give it a try.

In order to redirect to the dashboard use this in a controller

```
$this->_redirect('adminhtml/dashboard/index');
```

If that does not work for you then post your code in the question.

Comment: thanks Marius, i too figured that, i got a clue in config.xml of adminhtml.

Comment: @MTM. Either accept this answer if it solved your problem or add your own answer describing what you did to solve the problem and accept that one.

Comment: the upvote you see for your answer is of mine :)